# Find the first appearance of an address with value 0xFFFFFFFF in a contiguous memory space, using binary search

Tags: c, embedded, binary-search

I need to store a 4 bytes number in a flash memory. I can't erase/write the number every time, because the flash memories have a limited number of write/erase cycles. To avoid breaking the flash too fast, I've reserved a full page just for this counter. On each write, I write the number on the next four bytes. Once the full page is written, I erase the page and I start writing from the first address.

To implement this, I need the following functionalities:

- Find the next free address to write(frist address with a value of 0xFFFFFFFF)
- Find the last written address(the last address with a value different from 0xFFFFFFFF)

The number will never have a value of 0xFFFFFFFF.

First I tried by just iterating 4+4+4.. and it all worked fine. Unfortunately, it turns out that the reading from the flash is too slow. I need faster algorithm. For my case, the binary search will be perfect.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
u32 FindNextFreeAddress(u32* arr, s32 l, s32 r, u32* address)
{
    if (!arr || !address) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (l <= r) {
        s32 m = l + ((r - l) / 2);
        if (arr[m] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {//when is found?
            if (m && (arr[m-1] != 0xFFFFFFFF)) {
                *address = (u32)&arr[m];
                return 0;
            }
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            l = m + 1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I am having difficulties figuring out when the 0xFFFFFFFF is actually found.  I see a problem if the whole memory is erased, meaning only 0xFF. The first address will not be found.

Also I haven't done anything for the other one

```
u32 FindLastOccupiedAddress(u32* arr, s32 l, s32 r, u32* address)
```

I guess I have to somehow reverse `FindNextFreeAddress`, but I'm still figuring it out.

Comment: Also, `*address = arr[m];` stores the value, not the address of the value. Perhaps it is `m` you are looking for?

Comment: So the data in this page will always be like: <non-FFFFFFFF data...><all-FFFFFFFF data...>`?

Comment: What problem exactly are you seeing with this?

Comment: Isn't the next free address always the address after the last written address?

Comment: Is the page initialized as 0xFFFFFFFF? If so, yes, you can do this. Otherwise you're not going to be able to. If it is, I suggest adding that to the question. :) However, I'm not sure it will help. Doesn't flash usually require an entire sector?

Comment: @Bop, yep, it should be `*address = (u32)&arr[m];`
@Barmar, I need to be able to find this address somehow
@StevenFisher, yep, the page is initialized as oxFF

Comment: @Barmar, yep the data will could be <non-FFFFFFFF data...><all-FFFFFFFF data...>.
It also could be only FFFFFFFF or only non-FFFFFFFF

Comment: @dbush I see a problem if the whole memory is erased, meaning only 0xFF. The first address will not be found.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica erased FLASH is always all ones. You can change it wrom 1 to zero but not the opposite way without erase

Comment: This is a known problem with "wear levelling" - it gets slow to execute. The correct solution is to consider such at the start of the project and pick an MCU with data flash instead, in case fast/random access is desired.

Comment: Btw the #1 question here is: "Is 0xFFFFFFFF a valid value for the data?" If not, then how do you ensure that it isn't?

Comment: @Lundin 0xFFFFFFFF is not a valid value for the data. The allowed range is 0 - 0xFFFFFFFF-1. When writing, if the value to be written is 0xFFFFFFFF, 0 is written instead.

Comment: Ok because it seems that for some reason you are using signed 32 variables and they can never have the decimal value 0xFFFFFFFF but they can have the raw binary value 0xFFFFFFFF (-1).

Comment: I am using signed variables only for the indexes of the array, the actual data is unsigned.

Comment: Arrays don't have negative indexes... Anyway, how large is the flash segment and what's the target? Is it a 32 bitter? Does it have data cache? Instruction cache?

Comment: Arrays can have negative indexes, whether such code is correct is a different topic.
Why signed? Honestly, I took the binary search algorithm from the internet and slightly modified it for my case. The indexes were already signed. It doesn't matter for the moment. I am interested of implementing correctly the search.

Comment: Again...  "how large is the flash segment and what's the target?  Is it a 32 bitter? Does it have data cache? Instruction cache?" It isn't professional to just start to hack away without establishing this first of all. It may very well be so that a linear search from the end of the flash is the fastest. I recall coding wear levelling for a MPC56 and benchmarked a few algorithms. It had data cache to compensate for wait states and similar, so a pure linear search ended up much faster. A binary search will jump around and "touch" memory all over the place, which isn't ideal.

Comment: The flash segment is 4096 bytes. All I know is that the read from the flash is slow, because it is emulated. I don't have access or knowledge of how the actual reading is implemented. I am working on a higher level and everything below is abstracted with read/write functions.

Comment: Ok then. It is mission impossible to optimize code for an unknown target. Writing a wear levelling algorithm without even knowing CPU data width or wait states can't be done. This is very close to the metal code and knowing about the hardware is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As it is emebedded target (FLASH memory) and you probably use gcc.

```
       #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
       #include <string.h>

       u32 FindLastOccupiedAddress(u32 start, u32 length)
       {
            return (u32)memmem((void *)start, length, (u32[]){0xffffffff}, sizeof(0xffffffff)) - 1;
       }
```

- `start` start address if the area in flash
- `length` length of that area

Comment: FindLastOccupiedAddress() should return the last address with a value different from 0xFFFFFFFF. The last address on which something was written. Binary search must also be used.

Comment: @MartinChekurov subtracting one is not very difficult to implement

Comment: Couldn't this find an unwanted sequence of bytes 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff split across a u32 boundary? Also what is the value of `sizeof(0xffffffffff)`? (Probably 8 on most systems.) What's wrong with `sizeof(u32)`? What's with the out-of-range initializer in the compound literal `(u32[]){0xffffffffff}`?

Comment: While this may work (subject to checking for splits as @Ian Abbott remarked), it is exactly what the poster does NOT want to do, because it is too slow. memmem does not (cannot) do a binary search, it can only search through the memory linearly because it does not have the extra information that the marker does not appear at the beginning and once it appears everything behind will be the same. That property enables the faster binary search.

Comment: @IanAbbott 1. it was obvious typo (yes it is hard to count to 8)

Comment: By definition, it will always be faster to search from the end of the flash block instead of the beginning. Unless perhaps there's data cache on the MCU, then it gets harder to predict the best algorithm.

Comment: @Lundin by definition?

Answer (score 0):

This check:

```
if (m && (arr[m-1] != 0xFFFFFFFF)) {
```

Will always be false when `m` is 0, i.e. on the first element of the list.  So you want the check to pass if you're on the first element *or* if the previous element is not the flag value:

```
if (!m || (arr[m-1] != 0xFFFFFFFF)) {
```

Comment: This seems to handle the case for the first element. Will test it tomorrow.

Comment: If `m` is 0 the flash is full and we can stop searching. This would be where you have to erase flash and then start over from index zero.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a slightly different approach.

At each iteration, divide `n` by 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const uint32_t* FindNextFreeAddress(const uint32_t *arr, size_t n) {
  const uint32_t *end = NULL;
  size_t i = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    size_t mid = n / 2;
    if (arr[i + mid] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
      n = mid;
      end = &arr[i + mid];
    } else {
      i += mid + 1;
      n = n - mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return end;
}

void test(const uint32_t *arr, size_t n) {
  const uint32_t *p = FindNextFreeAddress(arr, n);
  if (p) {
    size_t index = (size_t) (p - arr);
    printf("Offset %zu, last written address contents: %lu\n", //
        index, (unsigned long) (index > 0 ? arr[index - 1] : 0));
  } else {
    printf("Empty\n");
  }
}


int main() {
  uint32_t a[4] = {123, 456, 789, 012};
  test(a, 4);
  uint32_t b[4] = {123, 456, 789, -1u};
  test(b, 4);
  uint32_t c[4] = {123, -1u, -1u, -1u};
  test(c, 4);
  uint32_t d[4] = {-1u, -1u, -1u, -1u};
  test(d, 4);
  puts("");
  uint32_t e[5] = {123, 456, 789,  12, 345};
  test(e, 5);
  uint32_t f[3] = {123, 456, 789};
  test(f, 3);
  uint32_t g[5] = {-1u, -1u, -1u, -1u, -1u};
  test(g, 5);
  uint32_t h[3] = {-1u, -1u, -1u};
  test(h, 3);
  puts("");
  uint32_t i[5] = {123, 456, -1u, -1u, -1u};
  test(i, 5);
  uint32_t j[3] = {123, 456, -1u};
  test(j, 3);
}
```

Output

```
Empty
Offset 3, last written address contents: 789
Offset 1, last written address contents: 123
Offset 0, last written address contents: 0

Empty
Empty
Offset 0, last written address contents: 0
Offset 0, last written address contents: 0

Offset 2, last written address contents: 456
Offset 2, last written address contents: 456
```

When `FindNextFreeAddress(arr, n)` returns `NULL`, the last written address is `&arr[n-1]`.

When `FindNextFreeAddress(arr, n)` returns `a`, the last written address is NULL.

When `FindNextFreeAddress(arr, n)` returns more than `a`, the last written address is `a-1`.

Comment: Martin Chekurov, Tip: if array size is always a power of 2, some micro-optimizations are possible.